# How can I generalize the use of these different data structures?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures

I have an application that reads times from a file.  These times can be in three different formats, based on flag bits elsewhere in the file, as shown below:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1]
public struct IntraPacketTime_RTC
{
    public UInt64 RTC;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1]
public struct IntraPacketTime_Ch4
{
    public UInt16 Unused;
    public UInt16 TimeHigh;
    public UInt16 TimeLow;
    public UInt16 MicroSeconds;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1]
public struct IntraPacketTime_IEEE1588
{
    public UInt32 NanoSeconds;
    public UInt32 Seconds;
}
```

As you can see, all three time formats take up eight bytes in the source data file, but these eight bytes are *cast differently*, depending on the specified time format.

However, the output time is always the same format, regardless of the way it is stored in the source data file (either **YYY HH:MM:DD SS.ssssss**, where ssssss is fractions of a second, or **SSSSS.ssssss** as seconds and fractional seconds past midnight).

How do I read these times from the data file and use them in a general way, without having `case` statements all over the place?  Is there a software pattern that would simplify this, make it more generalized, and abstract away some of the complexity?

Comment: you might be interested to know that the [code review proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/11464/code-review?referrer=aWNm_PdciyFqjFW8CUacGw2 "code review") is in the commitment phase. Help get it into beta by showing your support :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct IntraPacketTime {
    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private UInt64 RTC;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private UInt32 NanoSeconds;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    private UInt32 Seconds;

    [FieldOffset(0)]
    private UInt16 Unused;
    [FieldOffset(2)]
    private UInt16 TimeHigh;
    [FieldOffset(4)]
    private UInt16 TimeLow;
    [FieldOffset(6)]
    private UInt16 MicroSeconds;        

    public DateTime GetTime(IntraPacketTimeFormat format) {
        switch (format) {
            ...
        }
    }
    public explicit operator IntraPacketTime(Int64 value) {
        return new IntraPacketTime { RTC = value; }
    }
}

public enum IntraPacketTimeFormat {
    None,
    RTC,
    Ch4,
    IEEE1588,
}
```

You should be able to use

```
IntraPacketTime t = (IntraPacketTime)binaryReader.ReadInt64();
var time = t.GetTime(IntraPacketTimeFormat.Ch4);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend a repository pattern.

```
class TimeReader
{
    public void ExtractTimeFormat(StreamReader data)
    {
        // read the flag and set state so that ExtractTime will return the
        // correct time implemenation
    }
    public ITime ExtractTime(StreamReader data)
    {
        // extract the appropriate time instance from the data based on
        // the current time format
    }
}

interface ITime
{
    void WriteTime(StreamWriter data);  
    void WriteTimeFlags(StreamWriter data);
    DateTime GetTime();
}
```

The only case statement is in ExtractTime, the rest of your code can act on abstractions.